# Add div dynamically on button click using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to add div structure everytime I click the button to add an address using `jQuery`

```
<div id="container">
      <div class="address">
           <div class="input-reg rb-item input-group">
                 <span class="input-group-addon">Address </span>
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Insert text here">
           </div>
           <div align="center"><iframe class="map-img" width="100%" height="400" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://maps.google.com/maps?hl=en&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;ll=37.0625,-95.677068&amp;spn=56.506174,79.013672&amp;t=m&amp;z=4&amp;output=embed"></iframe></div>
       </div>
</div>
<div align="center" style="margin-top: 10px"><button id="btnAddAddress" class="btn btn-warning btn-md" type="button">Add Address</button></div>
```

and this is what I've tried but not working

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#btnAddAddress").click(function () {
      $("#container").append('<div class="address"><div class="input-reg rb-item input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">Address </span><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Insert text here"></div><div align="center"><iframe class="map-img" width="100%" height="400" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://maps.google.com/maps?hl=en&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;ll=37.0625,-95.677068&amp;spn=56.506174,79.013672&amp;t=m&amp;z=4&amp;output=embed"></iframe></div></div>');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Have you loaded jquery?  What error message do you get?

Comment: Not working means?? what it does?

Comment: I don't get error msg I'm using Brackets source editor

Comment: Have you got something like this somehwere in your code: `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>`?

Comment: your code seems to be fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/mrr643f1/

Comment: @sideroxylon I added the script still not working on me

Comment: @user3667305..try below answer..

Comment: Where did you add the script?  And where on the page is your javascript?  After the HTML?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to enclose your jquery code inside [**$(document).ready()**](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) block as shown :-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  //Jquery code here
});
```

OR

```
$(document).on('click', '#btnAddAddress', function() 
{...});
```

and lastly don't forget to add jquery library file on your page.

**Note :- Second answer should normally be used in case when we dynamically add html to the DOM otherwise use first answer.**

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kdya5598/)

Comment: @Azrael..jquery code should be inside `document.ready` block..plz read the docs carefully...

Comment: @user3667305...just enclose jquery code inside `document.ready()` as shown here.

Comment: Actually he has a point.. Since .click() is being used here and not .on('click'...) .. then the doc needs to be loaded in order to FIND the element on which to add an event listener on..

Comment: @user3667305 You should either do what Kartikeya suggested or.. $(document).on('click', '#btnAddAddress', function() {...} .. or both..

Comment: @webkit `$(document).on('click', '#btnAddAddress'` is bad idea in case of perfomance.

Comment: @Regent In a case where the page is loaded with more content then you're right, but for a page in the OP's example.. it won't matter much, Of course binding on doc ready is a better choice

Comment: @webkit about year ago someone explained to me that I can use `$(document).on('click', 'selector'` instead of deprecated `$('selector').live()` for dynamically added elements. And I used it and used it. Even in quite big projects, having a lot of these handlers... And only not long time ago I started to use adequate way of this `$('static_page_selector').on('click', 'dynamic_selector')`, and only if there are quite a lot of such dynamic elements. What I want to say is that it's much better to start making things correctly from the beginning without these "for small code this approach is OK".

Comment: @Regent.. very relaxed with this +1..otherwise people just downvoting with no reason...hahahaha.....

Comment: @Regent absolutely correct.. though I was using the OP's above code where a static selector isn't found to make my comment.. I wasn't giving an answer only making a point in a comment, but in general you're completely right, if I was giving an answer I would have noted best practice.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working fine [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/fc3nb5rL/12/). Also I have simplified your code like below.

```
$("#btnAddAddress").click(function () {
     $("#container").append($(".address").html());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you provided will work with out any modifications, if the js code is written after the button.
i.e.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
      <div class="address">
           <div class="input-reg rb-item input-group">
                 <span class="input-group-addon">Address </span>
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Insert text here">
           </div>
           <div align="center"><iframe class="map-img" width="100%" height="400" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://maps.google.com/maps?hl=en&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;ll=37.0625,-95.677068&amp;spn=56.506174,79.013672&amp;t=m&amp;z=4&amp;output=embed"></iframe></div>
       </div>
</div>
<div align="center" style="margin-top: 10px"><button id="btnAddAddress" class="btn btn-warning btn-md" type="button">Add Address</button></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#btnAddAddress").click(function () {
      $("#container").append('<div class="address"><div class="input-reg rb-item input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">Address </span><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Insert text here"></div><div align="center"><iframe class="map-img" width="100%" height="400" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://maps.google.com/maps?hl=en&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;ll=37.0625,-95.677068&amp;spn=56.506174,79.013672&amp;t=m&amp;z=4&amp;output=embed"></iframe></div></div>');
    });
</script>
```

Make sure that the button and jquery is loaded before your code is executed. The best option is provided by "Kartikeya".

Answer (score 0):

You need to add "return false;" at the end of click function.

```
$("#btnAddAddress").click(function () {
   $("#container").append('<div class="address"><div class="input-reg rb-item input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">Address </span><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Insert text here"></div><div align="center"><iframe class="map-img" width="100%" height="400" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://maps.google.com/maps?hl=en&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;ll=37.0625,-95.677068&amp;spn=56.506174,79.013672&amp;t=m&amp;z=4&amp;output=embed"></iframe></div></div>');
   return false;
});
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/L405g12L/)